# VB NET + Check if textbox have \/:*?"<>|

Tags: vb.net, textbox, symbols

I have a textbox when the user use /:*?"<>|, he cant insert symbols.

```
    Private Sub TextBox2_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = ">"c Or e.KeyChar = "<"c Or e.KeyChar = "\"c Or e.KeyChar = "/"c Or e.KeyChar = ":"c Or e.KeyChar = "*"c Or e.KeyChar = "?"c Or e.KeyChar = "|"c Or e.KeyChar = "?"c Or e.KeyChar = """"c Then
        e.Handled = True
        MessageBox.Show("You cant use \/:*?""" & "<" & ">" & "|", "WARNING !!!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
    End If
End Sub
```

But how i do to check with a if to check if in textbox they are one of this symbols "/:*?"<>|" ? Because with a copy/paste.........

I try in a test.form this code :

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    If flag Then
        Return
    End If

    flag = True
    Dim InvalidChars = "/:*?""<>|".ToCharArray()

    For i As Integer = 0 To InvalidChars.Length - 1
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace(InvalidChars(i).ToString(), "")
    Next

    flag = False
End Sub
```

But flag is not declared and i dont understand bool.....

For the other i try in the same form

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
```

Public Class test

```
Private Sub test_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox2.Text = Regex.Replace(TextBox1.Text, "/:*?\<>", "")
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

End Sub
```

End Class

And textbox1 is the same like textbox2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several ways:

- Disable paste command in the textbox.
- Use `TextChanged` event to detect new text and then

  - Use a simple loop to detect invalid characters.
  - Use `Regex` on the entire text to detect invalid characters.
- Create an on-screen keyboard that allows valid characters only. Disable other methods of input.
- Allow invalid characters. Strip them upon submission.

### Simple Example

Add a `TextChanged` event handler for your TextBox. Add the following code inside the handler:

```
if (flag) return;

flag = true;
var InvalidChars = "/:*?\"<>|".ToCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < InvalidChars.Length; i++)
  txtYourTextBox.Text = txtYourTextBox.Text.Replace(InvalidChars[i].ToString(), "");

flag = false;
```

`flag` is a Form-level `bool` variable that prevents recursive `TextChanged` events.

To do the same with `Regex`, add the following code in the `TextChanged` event handler:

```
txtYourTextBox.Text = Regex.Replace(txtYourTextBox.Text, "[/:*?\"<>|]", "");
```

`Regex` class is available in `System.Text.RegularExpressions` namespace. Note that I'm not using `flag` in this case, since this will cause reentrancy only once.

Comment: Have you an exemple "Use a simple loop to detect invalid characters"  or RegEx ?